# Resetting form after click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a contact form.And when I click on the submit button it, it resets the form if I use .click(). However, when I use .submit() it doesn't work for some reason.

Here is the code for the form.

```
<form id="foo">
        <div class="form_sides"> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Your_Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Your_Email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Your_Subject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form_sides">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Your_Phone">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div id='success'></div>
            <button id="btn_submit" type="submit" class="btn_submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
var reset = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('form')[0].reset();
    },3000);
}
$('.btn_submit').on('submit', function(){
    reset();
    console.log("debug");
});
```

In this, I don't get the console.log, however on .click() I do get the console.log. The form is submitting to Google Spread Sheet. Also, while looking at it, if you guys can tell me how to make the reset smoother, that would be great. I want value's to fade out not the input boxes.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The `submit` event has to be attached to the form, not the button. `$('#foo').on('submit')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to attach to the submit event you have to attach it to the actual form.  If you want to do it on click you can attach to the button.  However, you can't do a on submit event of a button.

change:

```
$('.btn_submit').on('submit', function(){
    reset();
    console.log("debug");
});
```

to be :

```
$('#foo').on('submit', function(){
    reset();
    console.log("debug");
});
```

Alternatively you can attach to the click event of the button and have this code:

```
$('.btn_submit').on('click', function(){
    reset();
    console.log("debug");
});
```

Comment: Explanation: buttons are clicked, forms are submitted.

Comment: Added more explination

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you help me with fade out as well?  Can I achieve that with jquery?